Generator power inlet connect to outside main panel
I have a panel on the outside of the house with the 150A main breaker that then feeds to an inside-the-garage "main" panel (without a main breaker).  Can I connect a power inlet box to a 50A breaker in this outside box (below the main breaker), using an interlock kit? 

All you need is the right type of interlock. Based on some basic information (definitely Square D, meter main (a.k.a. "all inone"), etc.), this interlock kit looks like the right one for the job:

Just keep in mind that since your "main" panel is inside, you will have some running back and forth to do to move the interlock, connect the generator and start things up. In particular, you will want to turn off large load breakers (e.g., oven, dryer, EVSE, etc.) before turning on the generator, and that can only be done in the "main" panel. On the other hand, you can put the interlock right next to this panel since it is outside, which will make the installation a bit easier than it would be if the interlock was inside.

Thanks so much for the feedback!  I did find that same interlock kit online.  Running the power inlet box on the outside wall will be much simpler and less expensive as I can run a few feet of 6-guage wire through conduit straight into that panel.  (the panel inside the garage is recessed into the wall about 15 feet from the outside wall so this will make install much easier).  I will run a 50amp inlet so I think it should be able to handle most of this house minus the high-load stuff.
